# "Medium" or "mediums" or "media"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, nouns

Which one of these would be correct:

> (XYZ offers) significantly more visibility than other
>
> - medium
> - mediums
> - media
> - mode (?)
>
> of advertisements.

XYZ is a new method of advertisements, similar to TV, radio, and newspapers. How would you go about comparing it to the other methods(?) of advertisements.

I'm not using *media* as in "mass communication", but rather as in "medium of instruction" or "medium of travel".

Comment: I think if you change *of* to *suitable for carrying*, your sentence might just about make sense with **media**, but I rather doubt that *XYZ* really is a new 'medium' ranking alongside TV/Press/Radio/etc. (or Watercolour/Photography/Sculpture if we loosen the definition to one not normally pluralised in that sense).

Comment: *Mediums* is the plural when it is used for an intermediate state or a person who talks to spirits. *Media* is the plural when talking about communication or art materials. So you want *media*.

Comment: Media is for news and other mass-communication methods. This is not the intended usage as per stated.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I was prepared to buy into *rooting mediums* yesterday, and NGrams satisfied me this usage does exist. Today I also discover *transmission mediums* is far from unknown, but in both cases the *incorrect* form seems almost exclusively US, not UK. Right or wrong, though, *rooting media* does make me cringe.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: how do you decide which plural is incorrect for *rooting medium* and *transmission medium*? For the OP's question, at least, I think it's pretty clear that "TV, radio, and newspapers" should be pluralized as *media*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Well I'm assuming from your earlier comment that you restrict *mediums* to 'spiritualists'. And you know your onions, so I'm assuming it's 'correct' for me to use your version of *incorrect*. I claim no justification for me not liking *rooting media*; it just doesn't sit well with me. Nor does *rooting mediums*, frankly, but of the two that one is at least 'less bad' to my ear.

Comment: ...btw - I didn't count them, but my impression is that in this American-NGram for **other mediums**, half or more are *not* about spiritualists.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that wasn't what I was trying to say. What I meant to say was that *oils, pastels, and watercolors* are *media*; *newspapers, TV, and radio* are *media*; clothing sized between small and large are *mediums*; and spiritualists are *mediums*. I was not trying to include any other uses.

Comment: @Caption Nemo: You say that what you want the plural for is similar to TV, radio, and newspapers. These are definitely *media.* (And in fact, these, possibly together with some other communication means, comprise *mass media*; this is where *mass media* gets its name.)

Comment: @Peter Shor: Not sure if we're disagreeing or not. The sense of *medium* for *rooting compound* is obviously in the same class as *oils/pastels/watercolors*, and by standard grammar of course the plural is *media*. I don't say *mediums* is 'correct', nor do I claim that finding a significant minority of US writers using it makes it any more defensible. I'm just saying *rooting media* sounds awkward to my ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the usage OP wants is supported by any words in the English Language. About the closest you can get is

**(XYZ offers) significantly more visibility than other transmission modes for advertisements.**

Or maybe **...than other advertisement vehicles.**

*XYZ* isn't really a new type of 'media' like Radio, TV, Newspapers, etc. - the similarity (as implied by the target sentence), is that - like them - *XYZ* is capable of delivering adverts. Most likely - unlike them - carrying advertisements is its primary purpose. Mainstream English doesn't have a single word for the semantic category "method of delivering adverts".

There might be a 'trade jargon' term used within the advertising industry - but I'd advise using anything like that with caution; it may have unintended associations (as with [pitch](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/sales-pitch.html), for example).

**LATER** - I've now realised there's significant scope for uncertainty here because of confusion about the appropriate plural for **medium** in this context.

I take it for granted OP's *XYZ* can correctly be defined as an *advertising medium*, but it's my personal opinion that the correct plural for that meaning is *mediums*, not *media*. It's also my personal opinion that whichever plural form were to be used in OP's example, a significant proportion of the target audience would think it should be the other. Therefore I would avoid both.

Comment: its actually akin to newspapers (and other methods of advertisements). I'll clear up the question a bit.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo: Thanks. I'll amend my answer to reflect that clarification.

Comment: [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=advertising+mediums%2Cadvertising+media&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *advertising mediums*, *advertising media.* The predominantly used plural for this meaning is currently *media*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm interested to see that if we'd been considering this question 80+ years ago the relative prevalence of the two [alternatives?] would have been reversed. And I see no evidence that the earlier position was significantly affected by unusual phrasing for the 'spiritualist' sense. From which I conclude that my distaste for *rooting media* in particular is not just an individual quirk.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use *media* there. It refers to all types of mass communication.

You didn't ask the obvious question, about plural forms, but here's a usage note from NOAD as a lagniappe for you:

> USAGE The word *media* comes from the Latin plural of *medium*. The traditional view is that it should therefore be treated as a plural noun in all its senses in English and be used with a plural rather than a singular verb: : *the media have not followed the reports* (rather than : *has not followed*). In practice, in the sense ‘television, radio, the press, and the Internet, collectively,’ media behaves as a collective noun (like *staff* or *clergy*, for example), which means that it is now acceptable in standard English for it to take either a singular or a plural verb.

**EDIT** The OP has edited his question, invalidating some of this response.

Also, I didn't see that there was an end to the sentence: "of advertisements." I thought it ended with "media" ...

So, I wouldn't use any of those, except possibly *modes*. A better word would be *types* or *kinds*.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine exactly what *XYZ* might actually *be*, in order to drop it into OP's sentence as he requests. And even if it could fit the bill semantically, how could it be grammatical? *"Other media for adverts"* sounds unreal to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It sounds OK-ish to me, but "Other advertising media" would be better.

Comment: @psmears: Interesting point. On reflection I think I have a problem with *media* because that plural form has specific associations that are close to the intended sense, but not really a good fit. On the other hand, "Other advertising mediums" (which I think would be technically/semantically spot on) raises my hackles because of unavoidable confusion about exactly what class of communication channel we're trying to pluralise in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To me "advertising mediums" sounds like psychics trying to drum up more business ;-)

Comment: @psmears: It's true that the most common sense of *mediums* relates to psychics & such, but gardeners for example discuss *rooting mediums*, not *rooting media*. And that's the sense OP's example is concerned with. *Media* (as in *mass media*) is an accidental and misleading connotation that just serves to confuse the issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually I disagree - to me, at least, the sense as in *mass media* is the same as in *medium of instruction* (and indeed *multimedia*) - just as I would refer to paint, ink, pencil and crayon as *media* in an art sense. So using *media* in the sense of the question doesn't seem odd to my ear, at least :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To be honest, with my (lack of) gardening skills, the question of rooting medium/media has never come up :-)

Comment: @psmears: I was surprised to find there are people who write about rooting media - though as this NGram shows, you're definitely a minority. The semantic distinction I think I make is quite small really, and you don't normally talk about more than one rooting medium anyway, so I guess it's partly a matter of expectation and familiarity...http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=rooting+mediums%2Crooting+media&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3